# Query regarding sencha touch bar charts

Tags: sencha-touch

I am working on an application with sencha touch charts. By default the chart's left axis labels are aligned to right. I want them to be left aligned. I have applied text-align style on `chart => axis => label` in `ThemeList.js` as below:

```
"selector": "chart axis label",
"style": {
    "text-align": "left",
    "fill": "#FFFFFF", 
    "font": "9px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
    "font-weight": "bold", 
    "spacing": 2,
    "padding": 5
}
```

But I was not able to get them aligned to the left. I want to get the chart ouput as the chart image attached. I want to left align chart's left axis labels and to generate a line between labels. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By inspecting in the DOM structure you can check whether its Possible or not